# WPF WrapPanel/StackPanel with DataTemplate?

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

What must I do to use a DataTemplate in a WrapPanel or StackPanel?

On a ListBox its so easy but i cant find a way to do it on a Panel...

Edit: What i want is a ListBox that places the items like a WrapPanel.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can use the ItemsPanel property of your container.  I used something similar to make my ItemsControl layout using a horizontal StackPanel:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

So, more specifically for your case:

```
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

Answer (score -1):

There isn't a DataTemplate property for those panels..

You can however use a ControlTemplate for these panels, and set these in the Template property of these panels...

HTH